# Query running tally of in-stock products over time given a stock history table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a `Product` table:

```
ID     Name
--     --------
1      Product 1
2      Product 2
2      Product 3
```

I have a table that tracks when products go in and out of stock, `StockChanges`:

```
ID     ProductID     Date         InStock
---    --------      --------     -----------
1      1             1/1/2020     1
2      1             1/2/2020     0
3      1             1/5/2020     1
5      2             1/1/2020     1
6      2             1/3/2020     0
7      2             1/4/2020     1
```

I would like to list a range of days (in this example 1/1 to 1/5) with a running tally of how many products are in stock. For the data above, the goal results would look like this:

```
Day            InStockCount
----------     ------------
1/1/2020       2
1/2/2020       1
1/3/2020       0
1/4/2020       1
1/5/2020       2
```

On the first, both products are marked in stock, so the total is 2.
On the second, product 1 goes out of stock, so the total is 1. On the third, product 2 goes out of stock, so the total is 0. On the fourth, product 2 comes back, totaling 1, and on the fifth, product 1 comes back, totaling 2.

In effect, for each date in a given range, I need to find the most recent entry on or earlier than the current date in the StockChanges for each product and calculate the sum.

I'm using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has been end of life for several years now. This means in that time is hasn't had any udpates -- **not even critical security patches**. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Comment: "*On the first, both products are marked **out of stock**.*" Is it a typo?

Comment: maybe this fiddle will help us collaborate on this problem https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=5247d1ef-ebb6-4865-93a7-ae5fde5ba0f9

Comment: The way you've describe your problem, it _sounds_ like you just want `select [Day] = [Date], InStockCount = sum(InStock) from #StockChanges group by [Date]` however when I apply that do your data, I don't get your expected result.

Comment: @xendi that is what i tried also https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=aadc2ad6-d8af-43a1-8c86-7e250088c64d

Comment: *On the first, both products are marked out of stock* - surely it's the other way round?

Comment: Typo regarding the starting state has been fixed.
Tallying the reason the fiddle and simple query from Xedni don't work is that it's not backwards looking.
I need to tally the most recent entry - on that day or otherwise for every product. Note that some days don't have entries. The assumption is that the product stays in the state from the most recent update until it's changed.

The answer from @TylerEZPZGG below is close, but it doesn't work with a starting case where some products are out of stock.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - brain blip. 2014. Question updated.

Comment: @dubloons You've got about six months then before 2014 is in the same boat.

Comment: So have you tried anything???

Comment: I edited my answer to account for the issue that @dubloons brought up. The query now handles instances where the first row for the product starts with an initial stock of 0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach using a `RUNNING SUM WINDOW FUNCTION`.

1. Use a `CASE EXPRESSION` to convert any 0 `InStock` values to -1 and retain the existing 1 values, which makes calculating a running sum much easier. We then total these values by date.
2. Calculate the `RUNNING SUM` using a `WINDOW FUNCTION` by date.

The earliest version of a Fiddle I could find was for 2014, but this should work on SQL Server 2008 with no issues.

```
CREATE TABLE StockChanges (
  ID INTEGER,
  ProductID INTEGER,
  Date DATETIME,
  InStock INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO StockChanges
  (ID, ProductID, Date, InStock)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2020-01-01', '1'),
  ('2', '1', '2020-01-02', '0'),
  ('3', '1', '2020-01-05', '1'),
  ('5', '2', '2020-01-01', '1'),
  ('6', '2', '2020-01-03', '0'),
  ('7', '2', '2020-01-04', '1');

SELECT a.Date,
       SUM(a.InStockCount) OVER (ORDER BY a.DATE) AS InStockCount      
FROM
  (SELECT a.Date,
          SUM(CASE
                  WHEN a.InStock = 0 THEN -1
                  WHEN a.InStock = 1 THEN 1
              END) AS InStockCount
   FROM StockChanges a
   GROUP BY a.Date) a
```

| Date | InStockCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2 |

**EDIT: THIS VERSION HANDLES INSTANCES WHERE INITIAL STOCK FOR PRODUCT IS ZERO**

This prevents the product stock from being converted to -1 if it is the first ever row for the product. I use `ROW_NUMBER` to assign a value of 1 to the first ever product row. If the `ROW_NUMBER` = 1 and the `InStock` value is 0, then we leave the value as zero.

```
CREATE TABLE StockChanges (
  ID INTEGER,
  ProductID INTEGER,
  Date DATETIME,
  InStock INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO StockChanges
  (ID, ProductID, Date, InStock)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2020-01-01', '1'),
  ('2', '1', '2020-01-02', '0'),
  ('3', '1', '2020-01-05', '1'),
  ('5', '2', '2020-01-01', '1'),
  ('6', '2', '2020-01-03', '0'),
  ('7', '2', '2020-01-04', '1'),
  ('8', '3', '2020-01-07', '0');


SELECT a.Date,
       SUM(a.InStockCount) OVER (
                                 ORDER BY a.DATE) AS InStockCount
FROM
  (SELECT a.Date,
          SUM(a.InStockCount) AS InStockCount
   FROM
     (SELECT a.Id,
             a.ProductID,
             a.Date,
             a.Instock,
             CASE /* HANDLE ZERO STOCK FOR FIRST PRODUCT STOCK ROW  */
                 WHEN a.InStock = 0
                      AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.ProductId
                                             ORDER BY a.Date) = 1 THEN 0
                 WHEN a.InStock = 0 THEN -1
                 WHEN a.InStock = 1 THEN 1
             END AS InStockCount
      FROM StockChanges a) a
   GROUP BY a.Date) a
```

| Date | InStockCount |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2020-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2020-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2020-01-07 00:00:00.000 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hI_xudJr)

Comment: The only issue is that a product can start with zero inventory. If this happens, it ends up counting as a -1 rather than a zero when it's out of stock and 0 rather than 1 when it's in stock. Any thoughts?

Comment: @dubloons, I edited my answer with logic to handle this. I added the "3" ProductId to demonstrate/test.